# I cannot move my img element in CSS

Tags: css, position

Why can't I move a picture a little bit to the left? I can move it to the right, but not left. I have used margin and padding; neither worked. Here is the HTML:

```
<aside id="sidenews">
    <img src="live.jpg" alt="Mountain View">
```

and CSS:

```
#sidenews {
    float:right;
    margin: 40px 0px;
    padding:15px;
    border:1px solid yellow;
    height: 305px;
    width: 247px;
}

aside img {
    margin:0px;
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your aside img from `margin: 0;` and `margin-right: 0;` to `margin: 0 5px 0 0;` because your `margin: 0;` is rendering your margin-right unusable unless you want to add `margin-right: 5 !important;`

```css
aside img {
    margin: 0 5px 0 0; /* this will work */
}
```

Comment: thank you for responding didnt know somebody will actually respond: i want to place the picture inside the yellow borders but cannot : because nobody answered untill now i changed a little bit here is html: <aside id="side_news">

</aside>
<div id="pic">
     <img src="live.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >
 </div>         and css: #side_news{
float:right;
margin: 40px 0px;
padding:15px;
border:1px solid yellow;
height: 305px;
width: 247px;
}
#pic{
clear:both;
margin-left:730px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 850px;

}

Comment: @waleedd32 You're welcome. Need anymore help with questions about HTML/CSS just ask.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it a little bit i want to place the picture inside the yellow borders i managed to place it but you know when i press ctrl and and scroll with mouse make page smaller or bigger then the picture goes up and down why this happens here is html:

```
< aside id="side_news" >

< / aside >

< div id = " pic ">

     < img src= " live.jpg" alt= " Mountain View " >

 < / div >

and css:

#side_news{ 

float:right;

margin: 40px 0px; 

padding:15px; border:1px solid yellow; 

height: 305px;

width: 247px; 

} #pic{ 

clear:both; 

margin-left:730px; 

position: relative; 

bottom: 990px;

 }
```

Comment: In order to format your code, select it all and press CTRL + K